# Text-align is not working on a img tag

Tags: html, css, image, text-align

Take a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jVsQY/

As you can see, I'm using `text-align: center` on a image tag, with a class and it doesn't show any results.

I was trying using an `display: inline-block` and so, but did not helped.

Comment: Nice empty fiddle you have there.

Comment: You have to set `text-align: center` on the parent. Alternatively, you can set the following on your image: `display: block; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: You just linked to jsfiddle.net -- not the actual fiddle you had (presumably) created.

Comment: What a facepalm... Edited my fiddle url xD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To center align an image you need to do something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Or like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="display:block; margin:auto; "/>
```

Comment: note that it won't work if `<img>` is bigger than `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

If you use this CSS you will get the image centered

```
.center {   display: block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;}
```

Comment: Is this added to the image or the container?